# AnkhSVN - Equivalent to eclipse's "override and update"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ankhsvn

I'm new to AnkhSVN. I was trying to perform a total update of a project, overriding local changes with the latest changes in the repository.

I was used to the "override and update" option in eclipse + CVS, and I'd like to do something equivalent.

I tried the "Update project to latest version" menu option, but since it was giving me an error on a folder ("an unversioned directory of the same name already exists"), I deleted the problematic folder and performed the update. Now the folder isn't being downloaded anymore.

I'd like to solve this for this project only, without altering the other projects in the solution.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I was finally able to workaround the folder issue: after realising that the folder was actually downloaded but not shown in the Visual Studio explorer, I selected the project and clicked the "show all files" button. With the folder now appearing as hidden, clicked the "add to project" context menu item and now everything is fine. However I'm still curious about what would be the correct way of performing a total update.